# IST to UTC conversion in java

Tags: java, datetime, utc, datetimeformatter

I am trying to convert the date time string received (IST format) to the UTC format.

```
String time = 124200;
String date = 05/09/21;
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyHHmmss").withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")); 
String dateInString = date.concat(time);
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateInString, parser);
return Timestamp.valueOf(dateTime.toLocalDateTime()).toString();
```

This code snippet does not convert to UTC. Please let me know what is the issue

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Timestamp`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead with an SQL `timestamp` (without time zone) use the `LocalDateTime` that you are already producing. Since JDBC 4.2 you can pass `LocalDateTime` and other java.time types to `PreparedStatement` and other JDBC classes. Use for example `PreparedStatement.setObject()`.

Comment: By IST did you mean Irish Summer time, Israel Standard Time, India Standard Time or something else? I think you meant some time zone, not a format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short: Your parsed time is regarded as *UTC* because you attached the `ZoneId.of("UTC")` first. That means you take that time of day at that very date as if it was recorded in *UTC*.

Instead, you should have used *IST* as the original zone:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // time and date in IST (?)
    String time = "124200";
    String date = "05/09/21";
    // two parsers, one for date and one for time
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uu");
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmss");
    // parse the date and time using the parsers
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, dateFormatter);
    LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(time, timeFormatter);
    
    /*
     * until here, there's just date and time, NO zone!
     * If you apply UTC here, the parsed date and time would be regarded as UTC!
     */
    
    // create a ZonedDateTime with the desired SOURCE zone from the date and time
    ZonedDateTime istTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDate, localTime, ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
    // then convert it to UTC
    ZonedDateTime utcTime = istTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    // print the results in order to view the difference
    System.out.println(istTime);
    System.out.println(utcTime);
}
```

The output of this code snippet (implicit use of `ZonedDateTime.toString()`) is

```
2021-09-05T12:42+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
2021-09-05T07:12Z[UTC]
```

If your system has *IST* as its default zone, you can write `ZoneId.systemDefault()` instead of `ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")`, but I had to use the explicit zone on my machine, I'm in Europe.

Comment: Very good answer! OP: The `java.util.Date` and it's subclass `java.sql.Timestamp` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html). For any reason, if you want to return the `Timestamp`, you can return `Timestamp.from(utcTime.toInstant())`.

Comment: Continuing the last comment, you can even return `Timestamp.from(istTime.toInstant())` if your goal is to get `java.sql.Timestamp` instead of using the modern Date-Time API.